# Does CachingIterator cache incrementally?

Tags: php, caching, iterator

I would like to cache stuff from a list that really only *must* ever be retrieved once. The items in the list are callables retrieved from a list of files, and there must never be more than one access to those files. If the file is accessed again, it breaks the software.

I want to use [CachingIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.cachingiterator.php) for this. However, I am not sure exactly how it caches items. The list I want to cache items from may be iterated over multiple times, with a different number of iterations. While  I need the items to be cached by key, I also need them to be added to cache if another process makes more than the previous number of iterations.

So, does the `CachingIterator` support that? Or will it cache the list that resulted from the first iteration, and never go any further? Or will it just iterate over the whole list, which defeats the point of using iterators over arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `CachingIterator` will add items incrementally. In a list of 3 items, if the first time one iteration happened, then the cache will contain 1 item. If the next time 2 iterations happen, the first item will be retrieved from cache, and the second one will be retrieved from the inner list, and then cached. Etc etc.

This is illustrated [here](https://3v4l.org/0k2nY). Note how the first time there is one item in the output array, and the second time there are two. Note also how the first object is the *same* object in both cases, as is evidenced by the object number, e.g. `#1`.

Also, if your values are not stringable, i.e. cannot be converted to string, don't forget to remove the default `CALL_TOSTRING` flag, or use `FULL_CACHE`. Otherwise, you will get an error.

Another detail is that, if somewhere within the chain of iterators under the `CachingIterator` there is a [Generator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.generator.php),  that `CachingIterator` cannot be rewound, which means that it cannot be used in more than 1 `foreach` loop. This is counter-intuitive IMO, because I expected that, if it is caching, then it would iterate over the cache. However, apparently it still tries to rewind the internal iterator, which forwards this down the chain to the generator, producing a fatal error eventually.